# ng-repeat filter data in angularjs not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a data setup which looks like this

```
$scope.friends = [
    {
      name: function() {
        return 'steve';
      },
      number: function() {
        return 555;
      }
    },
    {
      name: function() {
        return 'mary';
      },
      number: function() {
        return 555;
      }
    },
    {
      name: function() {
        return 'jo';
      },
      number: function() {
        return 888;
      }
    }
  ]
```

Now what I want is to filter data on `ng-repeat` based on text input.To achieve this I have tried like this:

```
<table id="searchTextResults">
  <tr><th>Name</th><th>Phone</th></tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:search">
    <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.number}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Where input is defined like `<input type="text" ng-model="search.name"/>`.
But  the filter does not work.I have tried and come to see if I modify the data structure like this

```
$scope.friends = [
{
  name:'steve',
  number: 555          
},
{
  name:'marry',
  number: 555
},
{
 name:'steve',
  number: 888
} 

 ]
```

then only this works.However I want to keep my data structure as it is.

Can anyone please help on this how can I filter having the above data structure.

<kbd>[plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/y7utpLAmzFsNwZLKnIaN?p=preview).</kbd>

Comment: you original structure has each property as a function, so you have to call them like {{friend.name();}}

Comment: can you please be little bit of clear where you are talking about apply this?

Comment: Filter pattern objects will not work when the input array has getters instead of properties. Why are those functions anyway? If you really have to work with functions you wilh ave to write your own filter. But I suppose to change your data model to contain the strings.

Comment: @sowen note that data is getting displayed.only filter doesnot work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the `friends` data to achieve this requirement.
What I have done is using `angular.forEach()` function to modify the data and put it into a new array called `$scope.modifiedFriends`.

```
$scope.modifiedFriends = [];
angular.forEach($scope.friends, function(friend) {
    $scope.modifiedFriends.push({
        name: friend.name(),
        number: friend.number()
    });
});
```

Instead of ng-repeat on `friends`, I ng-repeat of `modifiedFriends`.

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in modifiedFriends | filter:search">
    <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
    <td>{{friend.number}}</td>
</tr>
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cYlmkaX1g4tmyKms1X7a?p=preview)